# Forcing parts of code to wait on others?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I was wondering if I can stop a function from even defining itself (basically I'm not using it, but it still defines itself, at least that's what I assume the problem is).

```
if (document.getElementById("loginLogoutButton").title!="התנתק/י") {          
    document.getElementById("username").value="asdf";
    document.getElementById("password").value="asdf";

    var target = document.getElementById("loginLogoutButton");
    var clickevent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    clickevent.initEvent("click", true, true);
    target.dispatchEvent(clickevent);
}

function loaded() {
    var targLpink = document.getElementById ("iconImage_3");
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ("MouseEvents");
    clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', false, true);
    targLpink.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(loaded,3000));

var msgodd;
var msgeven;
var messages;

//The first error happens here as far as I can tell
//"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

function list() {
    msgeven = document.getElementsByTagName("even unread");
    msgodd= document.getElementsByTagName("odd unread");
    var k = msgodd.length+msgeven.length;
    confirm(k);
    var i = 0;
    while ((i+2)< k) {
        if (i%2==0 && i+2<msgeven.length){
            messages.push(msgeven[i/2].id);
        }
        if(i%2==1 && i+2<msgodd.length){
            messages.push(msgodd[(i-1)/2].id);
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
    alert(messages.length);
}
setTimeout(list, 9000);
```

I then get an error on tagname:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I might also throw out that I have to use the setTimeout since I'm waiting for the page to load (it's not a different address, it opens up stuff within itself, so I can't use onload on that - at least when i tried it failed).

Comment: If your questions are marked as duplicates, that doesn't necessarily mean you were wrong to ask the question. As you say, sometimes you just don't know what to search for. A *good* duplicate will stick around the size, and help other people find the answer. Marking your question as a duplicate is meant (for a *good* duplicate) to help you.

Comment: Haha. +1 for "no jQuery answers". :P

Comment: Try initializing "messages" like this `var messages = [];`.

Comment: T.J Crowder: I don't mind it being named duplicate, but when it threatens to ban me from asking it becomes a problem.
bjb568: :P
GSP: Alright thanks, I'll try it quickly

Comment: No error, but length comes as 0, so my tagname isn't working I guess, do you by chance see a mistake in it?
when an element has the quality class="", that is tagname right?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can copy *relevant* pieces of code into the textareas for html, css, and javascript.

Comment: Doesn't work (put it in and copy pasted the resulting script back), I think I'm using tagname wrong, is my comment above correct?

Comment: *Oh!* I think you want getElementsByClassName.

Comment: Umm, still getting 0 as length (should be 3).

Comment: Hm… http://jsfiddle.net/7SZ3E/

Comment: Does it matter if it's in tbody and stuff like that?
My classes are found inside some stuff, I'm not sure if I need to create some sort of path into them. - Up into TR to be specific

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54883/discussion-between-user336-i-actually-chose-this-and-bjb568).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating `msgeven`/`msgodd` as an array. But it's a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)! You can convert them with this:

```
msgeven = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("even unread"));
msgodd = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("odd unread"));
```

Comment: Hey, any idea why I'm still getting 0 for length? 
array.prototype... turns it/binds it into an array so I can use array functions on it if I understand correctly.

Comment: Updated, but the page doesn't seem to have that class.

Comment: It's in the jsfiddle (which by the way I'd appreciate if you could remove since it contains some info which I'd rather not be public).

Comment: Ok sorry for chiming back in, but it appears that my code isn't working.
Is there a chance it has anything to do with the function? Does javascript define it before I even use it (basically I enter a page where it's relevant, but could it be that it defines itself before and so finds nothing?)

Comment: Removing the fiddle wouldn't work very well, it's still on jsfiddle and in the revision history (if you really want it removed from the revision history, you can flag my post for moderator attention - a developer is needed for that). If you have more questions, you can ask it as a [new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: But this is the same problem, your solution isn't working for me.

Comment: Long discussions in the comments is discouraged, a new question would be better.